# Input non english characters into WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

I am using .net framework 4.5

I have a WPF project, and I use WPF combobox. The property `IsEditable` is set to `true` to allow input values.

But when I input non English character such as "â" (I have to type **"aa"** to make **"â"**, it becomes **"aâ"**.

When I set property `IsTextSearchEnabled = "False"`, **"aa"** becomes **"â"** (This is correct behavior).

Does anyone have solution for this when set  `IsTextSearchEnabled = "True"` for WPF combo box?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't get this behaviour when I type into a `ComboBox`. If you have something particular about your `ComboBox` or your computer that gives you this behaviour, you need to share it with us, so that we can better help you.

All the same, I don't know about typing **"aa"** to make **"â"**, but I do know that if you press **0226** while holding the **Alt** key down, it will also give you **"â"**. Maybe you could try using that instead?

You can find out more accent codes from the [Windows - Alt Key Numeric Codes](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html) page on the PennState University website.